# Very large files uploading to webDAV result in tomcat OOM errors

Tags: c#, tomcat, file-upload, out-of-memory, webdav

We are maintaining an older app written in c# that sends files (binary) to webDAV running under tomcat 8. My knowledge of webDAV is light. Basically, the c# client is doing the following:

```
// Create PUT request   
HttpWebRequest request = job.Context.HttpUtil.CreateWebRequest(WebRequestMethods.Http.Put, job.Context.Server, job.Resource.ServerPath);

// ...do some stuff to get the stream to send

// Now stream the data to the request
sourceStream.Position = 0;
request.ContentLength = sourceStream.Length;
if (DeserializeTask.IsSerializedData(sourceStream))
{
   request.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
}
else
{
   request.ContentType = "text/plain";
}

Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[0x1000];
int bytes;
while ((bytes = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    stream.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
}
stream.Flush();
stream.Close();

HttpWebResponse response = null;
try
{
    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    job.Context.HttpUtil.LogResponse(response);
}
finally
{
    response.Close();
}
```

This works fine. However, we have use cases where many users can be uploading very large files at the same time and we are getting OOM errors thrown from tomcat. Increasing jvm heap is not an option. I suspect that webDAV is waiting for the request input stream to complete and caching the bytes in memory before writing to the output stream (file) thus running out of heap. This would be a problem when files are large.

My question is whether there is a way to tell webDAV (via web.xml servlet setup of webDAV, some request property, etc.) to not cache the bytes from the input stream and instead write to the output buffer as each 1K of data arrives. I researched webDAV settings and http request settings and don't see anything that looks like it will accomplish this. Or are we to write a servlet ourselves to do this?

From catalina.out when the OOM is occurring:

```
554080 Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-exec-462" Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-exec-350"       at orgapachenamingresourcesProxyDirContextProxyDirContext.java1458)
554081 Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-exec-387" Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-exec-468" Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-exec-375" Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-Acceptor-0" Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-exec-364"  in thread "http-bio-8080-exec-255" Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-exec-341"    at orgapacheservletsDefaultServletDefaultServlet.java762)
554082         at orgapacheservletsDefaultServletDefaultServlet.java409)
554083         at servlethttpHttpServletserviceHttpServlet.java620)
554084         at orgapacheservletsWebdavServletserviceWebdavServlet.java378)
554085         at servlethttpHttpServletserviceHttpServlet.java727)
554086         at orgapachecoreApplicationFilterChainApplicationFilterChain.java303)
554087         at orgapachecoreApplicationFilterChainApplicationFilterChain.java208)
554088         at orgapachetomcatserverWsFilterWsFilter.java52)
554089         at orgapachecoreApplicationFilterChainApplicationFilterChain.java241)
554090         at orgapachecoreApplicationFilterChainApplicationFilterChain.java208)
554091         at orgapachecoreStandardWrapperValveStandardWrapperValve.java220)
554092         at orgapachecoreStandardContextValveStandardContextValve.java122)
554093         at orgapacheauthenticatorAuthenticatorBaseAuthenticatorBase.java501)
554094         at orgapachecoreStandardHostValveStandardHostValve.java170)
554095         at orgapachevalvesErrorReportValveErrorReportValve.java98)
554096         at orgapachevalvesAccessLogValveAccessLogValve.java950)
554097         at orgapachecoreStandardEngineValveStandardEngineValve.java116)
554098         at orgapacheconnectorserviceCoyoteAdapter.java408)
554099         at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
554100         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
554101         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
554102         at concurrentThreadPoolExecutorThreadPoolExecutor.java1145)
554103         at concurrentThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerThreadPoolExecutor.java615)
554104         at ThreadrunThread.java745)
554105 OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
554106 OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
554107 OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
554108 OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
554109 OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
554110 OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
554111 OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
554112 OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Thanks for any suggestions.
--Pat

Comment: Can you post a stack trace from your OOME if one is available?

Comment: I've edited post to include what we have from the catalina.out from tomcat when it fails.

Comment: It looks like your stack trace is a little corrupted. Can you verify that the copy/paste has preserved as much detail as possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some solutions that might help:

- Upload the attachment to a dedicated file server and provide a link to that resource in your put request. **Expensive** unless you already have a more modern fileserver else where.
- If at least one upload succeeds you could create a more graceful implementation that when receiving the exception wait for a couple of **random** (this is important) seconds between (1 and 10 or so) and try again. Until all the uploads have been completed. **Advanced** this might need some tweaking over time and might be difficult to get right
- Compress or deflate the binaries before sending. So blobs above a particular threshold should be compressed or if after compression still too big tell the user to split the file up in smaller chunks. **Not very scaleable** but might be just enough depending on the file sizes.
- Some webdav implementations support chunk uploads. **Not likely** as this is old code I assume the webdav server is not advanced either. Moving to a newer/advanced webdav implementation might be too expensive.

Hope you find something useful here otherwise let me know if I can help in any way.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question. It *may* help the original-poster solve their problem (upload files without errors), but it isn't actually an answer to this question.

Comment: If you have a better suggestion. Feel free to chip in. Some problems are solved in a joined effort.

Comment: I believe I have jumped-in.